# Book translation

Tags: translation

I found out that a great book by Ivan Shmelev "Солнце мертвых"(Solntse mertvih) was never translated to english. I'm trying to refer to it in my project. I'm confused with the translation of the name of the book. Should it be "The sun of the dead" or "The sun of dead". As far as I know "the" can't be in front of plural nouns while originally the sun in the name belongs to dead in plural.(Sorry for my english, not a native speaker)

Comment: Since the book was never translated to English, I would use a _transliteration_ of the title, not a _translation_. I would also include the title somewhere in Cyrillic, since there may be multiple transliteration schemes for the Cyrillic alphabet. Google Translate gives the translation as "Sun of the Dead", which is quite acceptable as a translation. On the other hand, googling for "pronunciation of Солнце мертвых" turns up a link to genius.com which translates it as "The Sun of the Dead", which is equally acceptable.

Comment: There is at least one English translation, by J.C.Hogarth, J.M. Dent and Sons Ltd., 1927. Hogarth used the title *The Sun of the Dead*. See also [this](https://kb.osu.edu/dspace/bitstream/handle/1811/82085/1/CSEES_MWSC_2017_Smirnova_paper.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using *the* before plural nouns:

> **The women** present cheered her.
>   **The bandits** looted the town.

And with a 'nominalized' adjective, *the ADJ* usually has plural reference: "all those who are *ADJ*":

> **The poor** suffer most during a famine.
>   **The sensitive** will not enjoy this story.

In English *the ADJ* has singular reference only in very restricted circumstances: typically, in contexts where *ADJ* has been previously established as a category.

So my vote goes to *The Sun of **the** Dead*.